# SystemJS - ES6 Module Loader - excessive hierarchy in import

Tags: javascript, dependency-management, systemjs, es6-module-loader

I'm just starting out with SystemJS and the ES6 module loader. I have a simple test module:

```
var Feature = {
    init : function(){
        console.log("Feature.init");
    }
};
export {Feature};
```

Which then gets imported

```
System.import('js/feature.js').then(function(Feature){
    Feature.init();
});
```

Which then throws an error

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Feature.init is not a function
```

However if I call init like this instead it works

```
System.import('js/feature.js').then(function(Feature){
    Feature.Feature.init();
});
```

I'm not sure where the parent object is coming from, or if there's a way to bypass it. What am I missing?

Comment: You're using a named export, and the promise seems to resolve with the module namespace

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
export {Feature};
```

Transpiles to:

```
module.exports.Feature = Feature;
```

You're probably looking for the ES6 `default` keyword:

```
export default Feature;
```

Which transpiles to:

```
module.exports = Feature;
```

Comment: I tried that also but it didn't provide the expected result. In fact it gave me even more hierarchy to have to deal with: 

`Feature.default.Feature.init();`

Was the only way to get to the function after including the 'default'

Comment: That shouldn't be the case.  Your transpiler may be doing something incorrect.  http://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=var%20Feature%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20init%3A%20function()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20alert('hello'%2C%20'world')%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aexport%20default%20Feature%3B

Comment: @TbWill4321: babel 6 does it different now

Comment: Bergi, could you provide more detail. So far the two comments you've made haven't added any clarity as to how to resolve the problem.

Comment: @TbWill4321 I'm using the default traceur. Switching over to babel (browser.js) and setting System.config transpiler to babel ends up throwing errors from browser.js about: 

`Uncaught (in promise) Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'keys' of undefined.`

Comment: Okay, got babel browser.js working properly and get identical results now to what traceur was providing.